# How can I find the minimum value of this expression?

Tags: geometry

> A straight line $L$ with negative slope passes through point $(8,2)$ and cuts the positive coordinate axis at $P$ and $Q$. As $L$ varies, what is the absolute minimum value of $OP+OQ$? ($O$ is origin)

I got the point-slope form of the line as $$y-2=m(x-8),m<0$$ and the points as $P(8-2/m, 0)$ and $Q(0, 2-8m)$.

So, $$OP+OQ=10-\frac{2}{m}-8m$$ So how can I find the minimum value of this expression?

Comment: Do you know about calculus? Derivatives and such?

Comment: Yes, I do. Anyway, I got the answer. You have any alternative ways to find the minimum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To minimize the function $f(m) = 10 - 2/m - 8m$, you can compute where the derivative is zero to find the local extrema : 
$$
f'(m) = \frac 2{m^2} - 8 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad m^2 = 1/4, m \in \{\pm 1/2\}.
$$
Since our slopes are negative, the only possible extrema in our case is $m=-1/2$. Since the second derivative of $f$ is $f''(m) = \frac{-4}{m^3}$ which is always positive when $m < 0$, our function $f$ is convex, which shows *existence* of a unique minimum at $m=-1/2$. The value of that minimum is $f(1/2) = 10 - 2/(-1/2) - 8(-1/2) = 18$.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 3):

you need to find the minimum of $\frac 2 {a^2} + 8a^2, a > 0.$  you can use the fact that $$\frac2{a^2}+ 8a^2 =\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}a - 2\sqrt 2a\right)^2 + 8 \ge 8 $$ equality when $a^2 = \frac 1 2$

therefore $$10 - \frac 2 m -8m \ge 18 \text{ for } m < 0$$ equality when $m = -\frac 12.$

Comment: Ah thanks, I understand now.

Comment: @SharatSachin, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=-m$, then your expression becomes $10+\frac{2}{x}+8x, x>0$. Rewrite it as
\begin{align*}
10+\frac{2}{x}+8x &=10+4\left(\frac{1}{2x}+2x\right).
\end{align*}
So,now the task reduces to minimize $\frac{1}{2x}+2x, x>0$ or, equivalently, minimizing $\frac{1}{y}+y$. But you can see that minimum value of $\frac{1}{y}+y,y>0$ is $2$ which is attained when $y=1$ because 
\begin{align*}
0&\leq\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt y}-\sqrt y\right)^2\\ 
&=\frac{1}{y}+y -2\\.
\end{align*}
Thus, $\frac{1}{ y}+y\geq 2$.

So, the final answer is $18$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the equation of the line be $\displaystyle \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$. Given that the line passes through the point $(8,2)$ and its slope is negative, that means $a,b>0$, and put $x=8,y=2$ in $$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$$

We get $$\frac{8}{a}+\frac{2}{b} = 1.$$

Now using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ......

$$\Rightarrow  \frac{\left(2\sqrt{2}\right)^2}{a}+\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2}{b}\geq \frac{(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2})^2}{a+b} = \frac{18}{a+b}$$.

So we get $$a+b\geq 18,$$ Where $a=OA.$ and $b=OB$.